# Favorite categories - not all favorite tag questions are colored

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, bookmarks

In my favorite tags section I have [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). When searching for specific questions containing, say, [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) I don't have all of the questions colored.

[image]

Should this happen? Do I miss anything here? Can we do something to *fix*(if there's anything to fix) this?

Comment: mabye the tag you're searching for is explcitly excluded from the coloring as favorite, because you're already guaranteed that all questions shown will have that tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When searching for specific questions containing, say, python I don't have all of the questions colored.

That's exactly the problem. As @Vogel612 correctly states in a comment, if *all* questions in the search result would be coloured, then it only highlights those questions that contain *another* favorite tag.